# Finding Control return Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, imagebutton, findcontrol

I have a control that add dynamically in **pnRoom** (panel)

```
 ImageButton imgbtn = new ImageButton();
 imgbtn = new ImageButton();
 imgbtn.Height = 25;
 imgbtn.CssClass = "bulb";
 imgbtn.ID = i++;
 pnRoom.Controls.Add(imgbtn);
```

And i'm received **null** value when finding control **imgbtn**

```
 protected void LoadBulb()
    {           
            foreach (Control c in pnRoom.Controls)
            {
                ImageButton img = (ImageButton)c.FindControl("imgbtn");
                img.ImageUrl = "~/path/images/bulb_yellow_32x32.png";
            }
    }
```

It's allways return null. I'm try but no luck. i need your help. Thanks !!!

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2):

- You have to use [`FindControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the `Id`you have assigned, since you use a consecutive number you have to use that instead of `"imgbtn"`.
- You have to use `FindControl` on the `NamingContainer`-control of that which you are searching. You are using `FindControl` on the control itself.
- If you use a loop on the panel you get all controls inside(non-recursive), so you don't need to use `FindControl` at all. You want  all `ImageButton`'s, you can use `Enumerable.OfType`:

  ```
  foreach(var img in  pnRoom.Controls.OfType<ImageButton>())
  {
       img.ImageUrl = "~/path/images/bulb_yellow_32x32.png";
  }
  ```

if you don't want to take all `ImageButton`'s or you're afraid that in future there are other `ImageButton`'s that you want to omit, a better approach is to give them a meaningful prefix and filter via `String.StartsWith`.

Presuming that you have given them all `imgbtn_` (and following a number):

```
var imgBtns = pnRoom.Controls.OfType<ImageButton>().Where(i => i.ID.StartsWith("imgbtn_"));
foreach(var img in  imgBtns)
{
    // ...
}
```

Remember to add `using System.Linq` if not already happened.